# WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed

Tags: python, path

```
WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
 Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no- 
 warn-script-location.
```

Why i am getting this error messg
and how do i fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add it to your PATH variable.

Example:

```
echo 'export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```